# Angular innerHtml

Tags: html, angular

I am relative new in Angular and I have the following question.
I have a component: **my.component.html**

```
<app-loading *ngIf="loading" message="Inhalt wird geladen..." delay="0"></app-loading>
<div [innerHtml]="content | safeHtml"></div>
```

And the following ts file: **my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

loading: boolean;

@Input() serviceUrl: string;

content: string;

constructor(public service: MyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.content = '';
    this.service.getMyContent(this.serviceUrl).then(myContent => this.onMyContentRead(myContent));
}

onMyContentRead(dto: SimpleDto) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.content = dto.output;
}
```

}

It calls a REST service and gets the dto.output, which is a string contains the following html content from **MyClassToShow.html**

```
<li id="myBox_panels">
    <a href="%s" id="myBox_page_link">%s</a>
    <app-tooltip [myText]="test"></app-tooltip>
</li>
```

The tooltip components exists, and looks like this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-tooltip',
template: `
    <a class="help" [pTooltip]="myText" [tooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition" </a> 
})

export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
tooltipPosition: string;

@Input() myText;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.setTooltipPosition();
}

setTooltipPosition() {
    ....
}
```

It seems that the app-tooltip selector is not realized, because its template content is not displayed on the webpage, altough I can see the selector on the console log.
The innerHtml can only contain plain HTML code?

How can I get my app-tooltip template as well?

Thnak you a lot in advance!

Comment: Angular isn't going to process that angular code if you just inject it as raw HTML. This sounds like it should be a [component](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview)

Comment: @Liam I have updated my question. I have a component already

Comment: You can't add a component using `innerHtml`. You need to read the docs

Comment: @Liam is a ComponentFactoryResolver a possible solution?

Comment: @dorcsi Angular doesn't process the content of innerHTML, so you can't have anything specific to Angular in it.

Comment: @user276648 Thank you! Any suggestions how can I solve it on the easiest way?

Comment: @dorcsi The best thing would be to only receive data from your REST service, and your Angular code would know from the data received it needs to display a `app-tooltip`. I guess another way might be to use Server-side rendering, meaning that your REST service would return ready Angular code, but I've never actually tried it like that.